# Hamburger button on iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, hamburger-menu

I created my own site through node.js/bootstrap through the webhost inmotionhosting. I have my site up and the hamburger button works on my android (S5) and I was at work telling someone about my coaching biz...they went to my site on their iphone and the hamburger button was not working? I don't know which iphone it is. My assumption is it is an iphone 4 as I have seen other people having this issue with that phone, but all those posts were with wordpress and other such sites..so I'm kinda lost. Any help would be much appreciated. site is www.HealthGainsCoaching.com - code is...

```
 <body>
        <nav id="topNav" class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                         </button>

                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Health Gains Coaching</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a id="headerLogoSpacer"><span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>

                            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>

                            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>

                            <li><a href="/scheduleasession">Schedule a Session</a></li>

                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <button class="btn services-css dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                    Services
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </button>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                    <li><a href="/14daycleanse">14 Day Cleanse</a></li>

                                    <li><a href="/privatecoaching">Private Coaching</a></li>

                                    <li><a href="/groupcoaching">Group Coaching</a></li>

                                    <!--<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>-->

                                    <!--<li><a href="/affiliates">Affiliates</a></li>-->
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <!--<li><a href="/store">Store</a></li>-->

                            <!--<li><a href="/successstories">Success Stories</a></li>-->

                        </ul>
                          <!--CODE FOR HIDING LOGIN/LOGOUT BUTTONS WHEN LOGGED IN IS BROKE ATM (FROM YELP C9)-->

                        <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">-->
                        <!--    <li><a href="/login"><i class="topNav fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Login</a></li>-->

                        <!--    <li><a href="/register"><i class="topNav fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sign Up</a></li>-->

                        <!--    <li><a href="/logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span> Logout</a></li>-->
                        <!--</ul>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

jquery...

```
$
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous" async></script>

$('.sectors').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#dropdown').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you are referencing jQuery or the Bootstrap plugins. Remember that Bootstrap has a second `.js` file that is responsible for triggering dropdowns, and this JavaScript file has jQuery as a dependency. Because it is a **dependency**, it must be referenced **before** the Bootstrap JavaScript file.

Take a look at the `<head>` section in the following working example:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="topNav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Health Gains Coaching</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a id="headerLogoSpacer"><span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="/scheduleasession">Schedule a Session</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn services-css dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
              Services
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
              <li><a href="/14daycleanse">14 Day Cleanse</a></li>
              <li><a href="/privatecoaching">Private Coaching</a></li>
              <li><a href="/groupcoaching">Group Coaching</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Note the order of the `<head>`:

1. jQuery
2. Bootstrap JavaScript
3. Bootstrap CSS

Following this order will ensure that your dropdowns work as expected.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help Obsidian! I happened to have them in the right order but they were all set to async so I think that messed it up. I fixed that and I'm gonna have my friend check it again tomorrow to double check.